# Jquery Validation & number field with comma

Tags: entities, 8

In my form i have this element :

```
   $form['poidsMin'] = array(
        '#type' => 'number',
        '#title' => $this->t('Poids minimum en gramme'),
        '#default_value' => $frais_port_entity->get('poidsMin'),
        '#description' => $this->t("Poids minimum du produit"),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
```

When i put 10 or 20, all is good but if i put 10.3 or 10,3 drupal 8 jquery validate tell me to insert a value like 10 or 11 with no comma.

My field in mysql is a float, how can i disable this validation for number type field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser support may vary, but essentially you want to add an attribute of `step="any"`:

```
$form['poidsMin'] = array(
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => $this->t('Poids minimum en gramme'),
    '#default_value' => $frais_port_entity->get('poidsMin'),
    '#description' => $this->t("Poids minimum du produit"),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => ['step' => 'any'],
);
```

Comment: Browser support for decimal separator in number field is horrible. It really works only for integer. For float use text field and validate yourself.

Comment: Or use `pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?"` or something similar @4k4

Comment: In UK that may work, but most of Europe uses a comma. All versions of IE and Edge can't handle this. Chrome and Firefox are almost there. IOS works perfect.

Comment: That's fine @4k4, the regex was just an example, it can be extended to support regional differences. Not sure where those browser stats have come from, IE10 & 11 support it, as does every other browser barring Opera Mini: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern. Safari (including iOS Safari) is actually one of the ones with only partial support

Comment: @Clive, I meant support for number fields. Pattern does not help much here. You want to use pattern with a text field?

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that's not so great @4k4. I would say using pattern on a textfield is slightly less evil than making do with a polyfill, yes. But only very slightly, and of course you do lose the step functionality. There's no good answer really